# What lenses should I use for bird photography

Tags: camera, nikon-d5600, bird-photography

I am looking for lenses to use with my Nikon D5600 that would be good for bird photography. I recently bought it and was wondering what lenses would be good. My budget is up to $400. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try too look for a used sigma 150-500mm they are in your budget range on ebay.

Answer (score 0):

Birds are small and far away.  You need a long focal length to overcome this.  The APS-C sensor gives you a 1.6 multiplier, but I can't imagine using a focal length less than 600 mm effective.  I fought with a 420mm for some years before moving up to 600mm and now I have 2000mm effective on a P900 and love it.  You can buy a shorter lens and add a teleconverter, but that slows down the lens and may ruin your autofocus.  That is a killer if you have birds that move around.  Buy the cheapest 400mm real lens or lens plus teleconverter that will autofocus, take pictures, and see where you have problems.  Manual focus will help a lot when the birds are behind some brush, which is common.  The shorter lens you have, the closer you have to get.

Comment: APS-C sensor gives 1.5x multiplier on Nikon cameras (1.6x is for Canon APS-C), but it's a little detail :).